# Chemical data of Lactic acid

Tags: plotting, curated-data, chemistry

I'm using the next *Mathematica* command in order to plot molecules:

```
ChemicalData["name", "MoleculePlot"]
```

But I'm not sure if the *Mathematica* database of molecules is complete.

I'm trying to plot lactic acid.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to exist a name of the molecule that makes the command work

```
ChemicalData["Lactic acid", "MoleculePlot"]
```

or

```
ChemicalData["2-Hydroxypropanoic acid", "MoleculePlot"]
```

So, I want to know if anyone has any suggestions about what to do in these cases.

Comment: No database of molecules is complete.

Comment: Yes .. But that one is an important molecule

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've struggled with How *Mathematica* expects the end-user to interact with knowledge databases for quite some time.  While this solution is likely not universal, it has been reasonably successful for many of my searches.

Using <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> to perform a free-form Wolfram Language input followed by using `CanonicalName` typically provides the appropriate string to conduct additional property searches:

[image]

*[Jason B.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9490/jason-b) notes in the comments that one can obtain the same information programmatically through `Interpreter["Chemical"]["lactic acid"]`.  I've included it in the answer in case the comments get removed in the future.*

Comment: For a programmatic way to get the entity, you can use `Interpreter["Chemical"]["lactic acid"]`.

Comment: Thankfully, one is not forced to refer to citric acid as `LemonAcid`.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Seriously!

Comment: Actually, in Swedish, lactic acid is called *mjölksyra* (milk acid).

Comment: @bobthechemist Totally off subject but I have seen it before and am clueless on how you make an animation to use in your answer. Can you guide me?

Comment: I can't perform the free-form Wolfram Language Input: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188021/keyboard-interacting-problem-using-free-form-wolfram-language-input

Comment: @JackLaVigne I use [LiceCAP](https://licecap.en.softonic.com/) on Windows.  I have not tried to do screen capture on Linux devices, although a google ssearch reveals a couple of free options.  No clue about MacOS.

Answer (score 5):

```
ChemicalData[Entity["Chemical", "MilkAcid"], "MoleculePlot"]
```

or

```
Entity["Chemical", "MilkAcid"];

ChemicalData[%,"MolecularPlot"]
```

[image: lactic acid]

Comment: But if you already know the correct name (in this case, "MilkAcid"), why not instead just use `ChemicalData["MilkAcid", "MoleculePlot"]`?

Answer (score 3):

What has been missed in previous answers is that one should have tried entering the name of the chemical under consideration in camel case:

```
ChemicalData["LacticAcid"]
   {Entity["Chemical", "MilkAcid"], Entity["Chemical", "LPlusLacticAcid"], 
    Entity["Chemical", "DLLacticAcid"], Entity["Chemical", "PolyDLLactide"],
    Entity["Chemical", "PolyLLactide"]}
```

which returns a bunch of matches. Note that the first entry corresponds to the "milk acid" entity featured in bob's answer. The next two entries correspond to the natural enantiomer of lactic acid and the racemic form, which may also be of interest.

Similarly, evaluating `ChemicalData["LacticAcid", "MoleculePlot"]` will show the expected plots, at least for the first three entries:

```
ChemicalData["LacticAcid", "MoleculePlot"] // GraphicsRow
```

[image: lactic acid molecules]

The OP almost got it by trying out the IUPAC name, what was not done was to write the name in the expected camel case:

```
ChemicalData["2HydroxypropanoicAcid"]
   {Entity["Chemical", "MilkAcid"], Entity["Chemical", "DLLacticAcid"],
    Entity["Chemical", "PolyDLLactide"]}
```

Comment: As an instructor, I wonder if Mathematica 'students' would benefit from documentation that describes the use of camel case or if this is a situation where one has to simply learn it on her/his own.

Comment: @bob, I personally think the docs could stand to be more explicit; unless you're already "used to" how *Mathematica* does things, you wouldn't readily think about trying camel case.